# Tomcat API : how to improve performance when client are closing connection after each request?

Tags: api, http, tomcat, connection

I have a simple Tomcat API and my goal is to manage the higher number of req /sec.

My problem is the following :

Scenario 1: When the client is using some persistent connections I manage to reach around 20000 req/sec using a single instance of the API. The server is loaded and the CPU of the server is almost fully used.

Scenario 2: When the client is closing connections after each request, the API only manages 600 req/sec and the server resources are not used at all. So I guess there is a bottleneck either on the global number of connections, either on the number of connections the server is able to manage per second.

What I want to know is if there is a configuration (on tomcat or on the server) that I can change to improve performance during scenario 2.
If not, which kind of resources is limiting? Can I address the problem by deploying many 1 CPU servers?

What I have looked to for the moment :

- The number of thread and connection in Tomcat config :
  I have adjusted theses number from default to 200 threads and 2000 connections, I don't see any effect during scenario2.
- Ulimit is set to unlimited
- JVM is configured as follow : JAVA_OPTS: -Xmx8g

Comment: The real question here is why are the clients closing the connection after each request? This was identified as a problem about 20 years ago. It's one of the reasons why we have HTTP/1.1.

Comment: I have no control over it so I am trying to understand what would be the bottleneck in the case in this situation.

Comment: Well really. The bottleneck is that the clients are closing the connection after each request. That is causing a new connection and possibly a new thread at the server per request. This is not something you can solve at the server end.

Comment: This does not really help. How can I manage this case better ? Put more servers ? Is there a point at putting big servers or should I deploy a lot of little servers ? I tried to deploy more tomcat instance on the same server and load balance everything, performance were worse.

Answer (score 1):

It was better if you provide more information about your deployment but generally there are some works that can help you to achieve better performance.
First of all you should measure the cost of each request and optimize it as much as you can. For example, if your API with each request, execute a query on the local database and this query is consuming a lot of CPU usages, you should optimize your query.By doing this your server can tolerate more request before its cpu becomes 100%.
Note  some tools like [JProbe](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/tools/jprobe/index.shtml) can help you for optimizing your API.
secondly, monitor your resources during the test and find which one of them becomes fully used. You should check **Network Connection**, **Disk**, **Memory** and **CPU** loads during the test and identify weakness of your resources. Track thread blocks and deadlocks as they are important to performance.
You can scale-up your server resources based on this information or decide to implement distributed architecture or add a load-balancer to your solution or add a caching strategy for you project.

In your Tomcat configuration there some settings which can improve your performance such as :
**Configuring connectors**
set maxThreads to a high enough value
set acceptCount to a high enough value
**Configuring cache**
set cacheMaxSize attribute to the appropriate value.
**Configuring content compression**
turning content compression on and using GZIP compression